# How we can load in Webpack fontello fonts in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using a custom icon font, made with fontello. When trying to use this in webpack, I get the following error:
**web pack.config**

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "react-hmre"]
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.json?$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }, {test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}
    ]
  }
```

**webpack.production.config**

```
      module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.json?$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'style-loader!css-loader')
    }, {test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'style-loader!css-loader')}
    ]
  }
```

[image]